# Python ldap подключение к AD , получение списка пользователей и их хеши паролей, замена хеша пользователя совпадающего со списком

Tags: python, администрирование, active-directory, ldap

Описание: есть windows server 2016 выступающий контроллером AD

```
ip=192.168.59.240 
dc=DTEST,dc=RDI 
login='Администратор' pass='passw@rd'
```

На другом сервере в другом домене, но в той же сети под управлением ОС Centos есть словарь пользователей с хешами паролей:

```
users_hashes = {'user1': 'somenthash', 'user245': 'somenthash'}
```

Вопрос: как с использованием python ldap установить соединение с AD, и привести всех пользователей и их -NTHash в соответствие со словарем? (словарь не статичен,со временем будет меняться, пользователи будут удалятся и добавляться )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предварительный ответ: так не получится.

Нельзя прочитать атрибут, хранящий пароль юзера, работая напрямую с LDAP AD, по аналогии с OpenLDAP, Sun Directory, etc.

Из-за внутреннего устройства безопасности AD этот атрибут можно только изменить специальным механизмом `смены пароля`.

Варианты прочитать хэш пароля есть, но требуют "вмешательства" в контроллер домена. Например, кулхацкеры знают способы вытаскивания хэшей из файла [NTDS.dit](https://blog.stealthbits.com/extracting-password-hashes-from-the-ntds-dit-file/)

зы но, как говориться, это не точно. Возможно я в этом вопросе отстал от жизни.

Comment: изменить в пошике атрибут пароля можно через :     'Set-ADAccountPasswordHash -SamAccountName p_morozov -Domain test -Server test  -NTHash 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx’ ', можно ли както применить эту команду через питон ?

Comment: @Андрей вызвать удаленно или если питон на сервере установлен? А если речь про возможность изменить пароль, то вроде как и из питона напрямую можно, не обязательно повершелы использовать.

Comment: вообще мысль была , ad контроллер на одной машине , скрипт запускается с другой, вопрос можно ли както забиндить AD машину и редактировать пользователей? в конце концов просто сделать соотвествие аккаунтов.

Comment: @Андрей да, всё можно. Биндиться к AD можно так: `binddn = "Администратор@DTEST.RDI"`

Comment: спасибо, забиндилось буду дальше побывать, я до этого пытался как к openldap подцепится